# Jquery autocomplete not showing the list of values that should appear below the input element

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I have been trying to implement the functionality to allow the user to select from a list which is created as the user types text in the input element using the autocompelte jquery api. However, my implementation is not working as it should, currently, I am able to log the text to the console as the user types but the same text is not binding to the input element that as it should. That is, the option to allow the user to select their option from a list.

I was able to accomplish the desired result using the $getJSON method, however, this method only works when the data source is not changing. This method does not work when I try to get the text that the user has entered in the text box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#autocomplete1").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "search1.php",
              data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
              success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#autocomplete1").autocomplete({
                   source: data
                });
              }
        })
    });
});
```

The contents of search1.php are as follows:

```
header("Content-Type", "application/json");
$items = get_merchant_name_by_user_input($_POST['keyword']);
echo json_encode($items);
```

The format of the JSON data returned is:

```
[
   {"value":"amazob","label":"amazob"},
   {"value":"Amazon","label":"Amazon"},
   {"value":"amazon","label":"amazon"}
]
```

Comment: With `dataType:"JSON"` works?

Comment: Yes. Actually I did not realize I didn't include dataType:"JSON".

Comment: Sigh, Thanks @FelippeDuarte

Comment: No problem. I've wrote an answer to document it.

Comment: You should also take a look at https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache as you can perform this logic without re-initializing the autocomplete source on every keyup.  Just ignore the cache part.

Comment: @Taplar I am going to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `dataType: "JSON"`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#autocomplete1").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "JSON",
              url: "search1.php",
              data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
              success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#autocomplete1").autocomplete({
                   source: data
                });
              }
        })
    });
});
```